# OnKeyListener and onEditorAction not working when using swype

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I'm trying to add submit functionality in an EditText when pressing the enter/return key on the soft keyboard in my app.

The following code works using the standard keyboards, but not with the swype keyboard (I have also done the equivalent onKeyListener).

```
et.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "enter was pressed");
                    addComment();
                    return true;
                }
        });
```

The method doesn't get called at all. Is this just a limitation of Swype? or am I doing something wrong?
if this is a limitation of Swype, how can I get around it, I have seen other apps do this, and it works using my swype keyboard.

My EditText layout is defined as:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:hint="@string/comment_hint"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />
```

Comment: I have the same problem with the Google Keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was a design decision by Swype (and maybe also google). Basically that if the edit text is multiline, you can't override the enter key, as you should be able to press enter and expect a new line. So it's really a UX thing, which I guess makes sense

Basically I had to add an additional button to submit the comment.